# Как передать значение последнему аргументу в функции

Tags: javascript

Хочу поменять только значение последнего аргумента в функции, искала инфу со спред оператором, пока ничего не нашла. Буду рада любой помощи

```
const func = (a = 1, b = 2, c =3) => {
  code
}
```

мне нужно задать с = 5

В итоге должно хочу получить

(a = 1, b = 2, c = 5)

Comment: разверните параметры в обратную сторону `(c = 3, b = 2, a = 1)` и меняйте, а иначе вроде никак

Comment: func(undefined,undefined,5);

Answer (score 1):

[Передать undefined?](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_undefined_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

```js
function func(a = 1, b = 2, c =3){
  console.log(a , b , c)
}

func(undefined,undefined,4)
```